# Help with linq to sql insert error

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

I have a database table with all columns to allow nulls for testing purposes. Between all of my columns I have int, varchar or bit datatypes. When I try to submit the form I get the following error message:

```
Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.
```

Here is the code:

```
using (storeDataContext db = new storeDataContext())
        {

            db.Dealerssses.InsertOnSubmit(new Dealersss
            {  
                AppFName = txtFName.Text,
                AppLName = txtLName.Text,
                AppTitle = ddlTitles.SelectedItem.Text,
                AppPhone = Convert.ToInt32(txtPhone.Text),
                AppEmail = txtEmail.Text,
                AppAddress = txtAddress.Text,
                AppCity = txtCity.Text,
                AppState = txtState.Text,
                AppZip = Convert.ToInt32(txtZip.Text),
                BusName = txtBusName.Text,
                BusCA = Convert.ToInt32(txtBusResale.Text),
                BusContact = txtBusContact.Text,
                BusDBA = txtDBA.Text,
                BusEIN = Convert.ToInt32(txtBusEIN.Text),
                BusEmail = txtBusEmail.Text,
                BusFax = Convert.ToInt32(txtBusFax.Text),
                BusMonth = ddlMonthStart.SelectedItem.Text,
                BusNumEmployees = Convert.ToInt32(txtBusEmployees.Text),
                BusPhone = Convert.ToInt32(txtBusPhone.Text),
                BusYear = int.Parse(txtYearStart.Text),
                Active = false
            });
            db.SubmitChanges();
        };
```

Comment: @slaks, the values being posted in the form are between 1 and 15 digits, therefore it is impossible for the value to be too large for an int32.

Comment: Your code will mess up the valid zip code 07055.  **Do not store non-numeric data in integer columns!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Int32.MaxValue` is `2,147,483,647`, which is only 10 digits long.
Your values **are** too large for an `Int32`.

Your Phone, Fax, ZIP, and EIN fields should be strings (NVARCHARs), not numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm betting it's the value for your phone number fields.  Int32 is a 4 byte integer with a max value of 2147483647.  Most phone numbers will overflow that.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is it is on your phone #'s Int32's have a value of:

-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647

So if you have the phone # of 517111111 (5,171,111,111), you are too large.

You should use varchar/char for phone numbers.